# .net core app on IIS using azure application proxy gets Forbidden 403 error externally

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-proxy

I have .net core app running on an internally hosted windows server running IIS 10.

The site works fine internally however I am trying to get it to work externally and cannot get past the forbidden message "Forbidden: this corporate app can't be accessed"  We enable it externally using azure enterprise application - application proxy.

On the same IIS web server we also host several .net mvc sites and they work fine externally and internally.  The application proxy settings are all the same, the permissions are all the same.

Does .net core need some additional configuration to work with the azure application proxy?

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? We're running into a similar issue. I'm guessing it's some sort of proxy configuration problem or maybe a firewall issue?